# How to pass context from MVC to IdentityServer login action

Tags: identityserver4

My use case is next: I have one "mvc" app service and a separate "idP" Identity Server service and I need to pass some context mvc -> idP so I can customize idP login page UI and I am shocked that something which IMHO is a super common scenario/requirement seems so far mission impossible to achieve.

Here is how my idP AccountController action looks like

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl, string position)
{
  ...
}
```

Now I've tried to pass this param from my MVC app like this

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"position", "Chef"},
};

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"position", "Chef"},
};

var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties(items, parameters)
{
    RedirectUri = "/home/index",

};

return this.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
```

That didn't work at all.

Based on my reading on SO and identity server docs I might have to use on MVC app

```
services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache();
```

but I couldn't find any real example on how to do this and not sure if there is something I need to do on iDP side?

Does anyone know a way how to achieve the goal of passing a challenge context from MVC app to idP app?

Answer (score 0):

As you know IdentityServer implements OAuth standard and it's communications are based on this standard.

IdentityServer as an identity provider indicates who is user, and provides any information about that user using *UserInfo* endpoint. So, if your are going to have any business logic, you should handle it in your application, not IdentityServer.

Comment: I understand that but: a) this all happens before the login so I can't use userinfo endpoint and b) it is about login page UI customization implemented on the identity server app service as described on IDS documentation so it is part of Identity Server implementation.
Do I understand your answer that it is not possible to pass context of a challenge and that the login page ui can not be customized by design?

Comment: It is possible to send parameters during Authentication, but required some implementation which required good knowledge about OAuth, OIDC and IdentityServer. If you describe your situation and your need, may be I will be able to help more.